# How can I solve this problem, res.json is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

My problem is the following, I send data with guzzle, and got error

> TypeError: res.json is not a function.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('get', 'http://localhost/data', ['total' =>  ['total' => 15]);
```

I tried the following 2 ways, but they don't seem to work.

```
exports.data= function(res,req){
    return res.json({ result: 'success' });
};
```

```
exports.data= function(res,req){
   res.json({ result: 'success' });
};
```

Node is working on port 3000.

> Error code: TypeError: res.json is not a function Or php page
> Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException
>
> Message: Server error: GET http://localhost:3000/data resulted in a
> 500 Internal Server Error response: TypeError: res.j (truncated...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter in callback method is `req` ,and then its `res`

so your method should be

```
exports.data= function(req,res){
    return res.json({ result: 'success' });
};
Or
exports.data= function(req,res){
    res.json({ result: 'success' });
};
```

You have interchanged their `positions`.That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks i fixed i changed