# TypeError: res.json is not a function in express.router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't know what have bellow error:
`TypeError: res.json is not a function`

I readed express documentation, and don't see any wrong syntax or other errrors.

Code:

- index.js

```
import express from "express";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);

app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 8800");
});
```

- ./routes/posts.js

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (res, req) => {
  res.json("This works!");
});

export default router;
```

Comment: I would leave this question open because it's a common mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve this problem, res.json is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507523/how-can-i-solve-this-problem-res-json-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

The arguments in router.get are wrong. Its `(req, res)` now `(res, req)`

This is how it should look like:

```js
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("This works!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the request object indeed has no `json()` function.

You mixed up the parameter names and called the *request* object `res` and the *response* object `req`.  Swap them to make it less confusing:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("This works!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

edit:

```
router.get("/", (res, req) => {
  res.json("This works!");
});
```

to

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("This works!");
});
```

the (res, req) has to be in a specific order

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the `Handler` is always `request` and the second is `response` often written in short from `req` and `res`. So change your code to this. More on this in this [routing documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)

```js
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("This works!");
});
```

> Note: Your code will also work if you change your `res.json()` to `req.json()` since you have switched the conventional names. But doing this is confusing and I will not recommend doing it.